# Lotus notes-Lotus script and symphony

Tags: lotus-notes

I want to create lotus symphony mail-merge using lotusscript. I know all methods and classes but dont know how to use that classes and methods...Pls kindly some one help me?...

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough.

1. First create a database that uses the Contacts template (or you can use your contacts database.
2. Create your document in Symphony. (I have only used the embedded productivity tools in Notes).
3. Select Tools->Mail Merge.
4. Click Browse that appears on the left, select your NSF file that contains the contacts.

After this you should have an "Insert Fields" list appear. You can add these to your document.

Then click "Finish Merge" and select the option you want. (Easier then LS IMHO).

... As for LotusScript. The following should get you started.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/symphony-toolkit/

Comment: Just had a quick glance at the toolkit on developerworks and it looks like an excellent way to get started if your already experienced with Lotusscript. If your not then you shouldn't be using it to get that experience, you'll be way out of your depth.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to use classes and methods then you don't know them at all. Here is a starter for you, I remember teaching myself lotusscript from scratch but its very powerful once you have grasped the basics.

```
dim s as new notesSession 'Instantiate a session object
dim db as notesDatabase
dim view as notesView
dim doc as notesDocument 

set db = s.currentDatabase  'This allows you access to the properties of the current database
set view = db.getView("<Your view name>")
if not view is nothing then
    set doc = view.getFirstDocument

else
    msgbox "Sorry, can't find view " & <your view name>
end if
```

Lotus notes is based around a container model, databases contain documents, views, agents etc, documents contain fields, fields contain items which have values etc. Start from the outside and work your way down and start small.

Comment: I didn't get the Help Content for lotus Symphony Classes.

Comment: You really need to post your own attempts to use the code and be as specific as possible with your request for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim symdoc As SymphonyApplication
Set symdoc = New SymphonyApplication
Dim documents As SymphonyDocuments
Set documents = symdoc.Documents
Dim document As SymphonyDocument
Set document = documents.AddDocument(”",True,True) ‘ Syntax is below
‘Set document = documents.AddDocument(Template, AsTemplate, Visible)
Dim range As SymphonyTextRange
Set range = document.Content.End
Call range.InsertBefore(”My Symphony document”)
```

This is the sample code for getting symphony documents. Now you may get a better idea.